# KendoUI - How do I get an attribute value within `kendoTooltip()`

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-tooltip

I'd like to receive the value of `type` of an input.

Docs: [KendoTooltip](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tooltip)

```
$("input").kendoTooltip({
        content:
            function () {
                return '<div>' + this.attr("type") + '</div>';
            }
  });
```

But I can't finy any way to work with `this.`.

Answer (score 0):

It was so simple: `e.target.attr("value")`

```
content:
    function (e) {
        var text = e.target.attr("value");
        return '<div>' + text + '</div>';
    }
```